# Can snapshotting be disabled on running redis instance?

Tags: redis, nosql

Is it possible to disable snapshot persistence on a redis instance without restarting it?

[Redis documentation](http://redis.io/commands/config-set) seems to imply this is possible. But how? I can see how you could turn AOF peristence on or off, but how can one turn off snapshotting (RDB) persistence?

Version of redis used is: 2.6.9

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You disable snapshotting by issuing:

```
CONFIG SET save ""
```

This is documented (in very few words) in your `redis.conf` file:

```
#   It is also possible to remove all the previously configured save
#   points by adding a save directive with a single empty string argument
```

Hope this helps, TW

Comment: Word save needs to be in lower case (CONFIG SET save ""), but otherwise a good answer.